# How Is `operator new` Implemented At The Linker Level?

Tags: c++, linker, new-operator

Per [the C++ documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new#Global_replacements), the `operator new`/etc. functions are:

> implicitly declared in each translation unit[, and t]he program is ill-formed [...] if more than one replacement is provided in the program for any of the replaceable allocation function[s]".

That is, if the programmer *does not* define their own `operator new`, then the C++ standard library *must* provide it. Conversely, if they *do* provide it, then the standard library *mustn't*.

**I understand this behavior, but what I *don't* understand is how this works at a linker level.**

The C++ standard library is compiled before the program that uses it, which is where the programmer is deciding whether to define their own `operator new`.  Thus, the C++ standard library does need to speculatively provide an `operator new` somewhere.  But then, when the user's program is linked against the standard library, if they *did* define their own allocation function, then that would result in multiple definitions and run afoul of the documentation above (in practice, you get a linker error about duplicate symbols, thank goodness).

Conversely, if the standard library *doesn't* define the `operator new`, then of course the user would have to do so, or else any call to it will result in missing symbols (and so a linker error the other way).

Comment: I don't think the language lawyer tag is going to help here since most of the linking step is implementation defined.  One way this can be done is for the compiler to find any `new` function and add it into a backend new.h file.  The library looks to new.h and gets the default if no override or the override if a definition is found.  This also allows the compiler to inject that file into all other TUs automagically.

Comment: If you're not coming from cppcon talk, note that windows simply does not conform to this, as it's loader (the stuff that resolves dependencies) does not have this capability.

Answer (score 4):

At least for ELF format, you can define symbols as *weak* using `__attribute__((weak))`.

If there are both weak and a normal symbols during linking, the normal symbol takes priority. So weak symbols can act as defaults or fallbacks.

The standard library can define `operator new` as weak, giving the userspace application an opportunity to override it but if it does not, the library's weak symbol is used, thus avoiding both the undefined reference and multiple definitions errors.

The same mechanism works with system calls usually, quite handy for mocking during unit tests.

Answer (score 4):

I can't refer to anything in the standard because I don't think there is anything in there about *how* it should be done.

Here's however an idea of how it could be done:

When linking, references to declared but undefined functions are put in a list of unresolved symbols until the next object file / library is parsed.

Since `new` is implicitly declared in all TUs, that's what'll happen if a reference to `new` is encountered before its definition during linking.

Once a definition is found, that's the one it'll use for all those unresolved references - and the one in the standard library will be ignored. So there *will* be two definitions: One user defined and one in the standard library, but this is an exception from the one definition rule and the standard merely says what the outcome should be. The word used is **replaces**:

[C++23](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/n4971.pdf):
6.7.5.5.1 General [basic.stc.dynamic.general]:

> 2. The library provides default definitions for the global allocation and deallocation functions. Some global
>    allocation and deallocation functions are replaceable (17.6.3); these are attached to the global module (10.1).
>    A C++ program shall provide at most one definition of a replaceable allocation or deallocation function.
>    Any such function definition **replaces** the default version provided in the library (16.4.5.6).

Answer (score 1):

> I understand this behavior, but what I don't understand is how this works at a linker level.

**"Knocking out"**

If you ask anything about "a linker", an answer needs the prefatory caution that linkers are not
regulated. Nor are the binary file formats that linkers deal in - ELF, PE, COFF, etc.
There are no formal standards for linkage comparable to the ISO programming language standards; no such thing as a "conforming" linker. Language implementers just have to get the
compilers they create to emit object code in a target format in such a way such that the language definition can be satisfied within the MOes of the system linkers that link that format,
or at least the ones the compilers support<sup>1</sup>.

That being said, the linker behavior you want to understand is basic and customary. The way in which a linker enables the C++ standard library's overloads of `operator new` to be replaced
by user-defined overloads is the same way in which it enables *any* symbol (a function or something else) that is defined in a default libary (the C++ standard library or some other one) that
you link into a program to be redefined with another preferred definition that you supply elsewhere
in the linkage. This is a commonplace practice, often described "knocking out"
or "overriding" a library definition with a user definition. (I eschew "overriding" because
knocking out has nothing whatever to do with the C++ keyword `override`.)

In linkage, knocking out is as old as libraries and only got beyond very simple explanation when dynamic
libraries and dynamic linkage came on the scene. It's reasonable to abstract what may be called the *Usual Logic* of symbol
resolution in program linkage for contempory PC/server OSes and show how it enables
knocking out. I will do that next, then as extra reading for fellow Linux/GCC detail buffs I'll demonstrate knocking out with the Linux GCC toolchain for
the case in point, the C++ function `void* operator new(std::size_t)`,
which implements the throwing scalar overload of `operator new`. I'll demonstrate cases for both routine dynamic linkage and static linkage.

**Best get some slippery terminology clear**

This is partly because the clarity is just needed; partly to clarify what distinctions are being set aside
when I explicitly set some of them aside for a while. My distinct definitions of **(un)resolved** and
**(un)defined** may depart from preconceptions.

- **static linker**: The linker we've just been calling "the linker" so far - the *buildtime* linker.
  It slices up object files and knits together the pieces to make a linked binary file (program or
  dynamic library) *targ* as completely as possible with those resources. But the object files
  are typically insufficient to finish the job at buildtime. Usually dynamic libraries will also required at runtime. The static linker has
  to be informed about them, but it can't slice and knit them together with *targ*. Dynamic libraries, by their purpose and design,
  can't be linked until runtime. What the static linker can do with them is drop notes into *targ* that will suffice for the *dynamic*
  linker to finish the linkage in the context of starting a program that requires *targ*. When we loosely say that a
  dynamic library "is linked" at buildtime, we just mean that it's input to the linkage and the static linker drops those notes in *targ*.
- **dynamic linker**: This linker comes into play when the OS wants to run a program `prog` and the notes that the static
  linker has dropped therein reveal that it depends on dynamic libraries. The dynamic linker loads those dynamic dependencies, then
  *their* dynamic dependencies recursively. It knits them altogether with `prog` to compose a complete
  runnable program, which is then allowed to run.
- **static linkage**: This is done by the static linker, but it's not the only or default sort of linkage the static linker does.
  It's a linkage that bans dynamic libraries, so any libraries it needs must be static ones. Static linkage has to be requested
  by an explicit linker option. You'll request it only when you want *targ* to have no dynamic dependencies and are prepared to
  pay the price of a bloated *targ*.
- **dynamic linkage**: Ambiguous! When we're talking about the dynamic linker, *dynamic linkage* is just what it does.
  When we're talking about the static linker, a *dynamic linkage* is a linkage that allows dynamic libaries.
  *Dynamic* linkage is the default for the *static* linker!
- **dynamically linked** (**program**|**library**): A program or library that has been linked by the dynamic
  linker? No! It's program or library that's the product of a dynamic linkage by the static linker. So it is
  program or library that *can be* linked by the dynamic linker.
- **static library**: A library that has been statically linked? No! A static library isn't a product of linkage at all. It's just a package of object files put together by a file-archiving tool, with a symbol-to-object file look-up table packaged in along with them like another file.
- (**external**|**public**|**global**) **symbol**: A symbol that the compiler marks up to be visible at least to the static linker.
- **dynamic symbol**: An external symbol that the compiler marks up to be visible to the dynamic linker as well.

*This one matters a lot -*

- **(un)defined symbol**: A symbol `sym` is *defined* at a point in the (buildtime or runtime) linkage of *targ* if the linker
  has bound all uses of `sym` to the same runtime meaning. Otherwise `sym` is
  *undefined*<sup>2</sup>. A definition of `sym` exists *in the program* if and only if `sym` is
  defined.

*And so does this one -*

- **(un)resolved symbol**: A symbol `sym` is *resolved* at a point in the (buildtime or runtime) linkage of *targ* if the linker
  has determined that `sym` *can be* defined. Otherwise `sym` is *unresolved*. As long as `sym` is unresolved the linker keeps
  searching for a definition. Once `sym` is resolved the linker stops searching. That a symbol is defined implies that it is resolved,
  but not conversely.
- **(un)resolved reference of a symbol**: A reference of a symbol `sym` is a use of `sym` in code, so a reference of `sym`
  is resolved, or not, accordingly as `sym` is resolved or not<sup>3</sup>.

**A simplifying abstraction of symbol resolution of program linkage.**

We're abstracting upon the default behaviour of actual linkers for routine linkages.

We can get away with viewing symbol resolution in program linkage as a single iterative process spanning buildtime linkage and runtime linkage.

The output of this process, if it succeeds, is a program `prog` in which all referenced symbols are defined. The inputs of the process
are a list of files:

- an initial non-empty part whose members may be object files, static libraries or dynamic libraries, in any mixture of those types; then
- a possibly empty part consisting only of dynamic libraries: all the recursive dynamic dependencies of the dynamic libaries in the initial part,
  in the order that the dynamic linker would load them.

We can set aside the following distinctions for the time being:

- **static** (**linkage**|**linker**) v. **runtime** (**linkage**|**linker**). We'll just talk about *the linker* and
  *linkage*.
- **external symbol** v. **dynamic symbol**. Since these are the only kinds of symbol visible to linkage, we'll just call them all
  *symbols*<sup>4</sup>.

Now for the Usual Logic of symbol resolution in our abstraction.

- To produce `prog`, the linker consumes the input files in supplied order. Let *file* be one of those. *file* contains symbol
  information visible to the linker that identifies the symbols for which it provides a definition and the symbols it references
  but does not define. After *file* is consumed, updated state-of-the linkage information is
  carried forward, sufficient for the linker's next needs. This includes a **ToDo** list of
  symbols `sym` that are referenced by not yet *defined*, specifying:

  - Whether `sym` is resolved.
  - If resolved, the identify of a *dynamic libary* that provides the first definition of `sym` that the linker found.

  For each *file*:
- **If** *file* **is an object file:**

  - *file* is linked unconditionally into `prog`, bringing with it 0 or more fresh undefined symbol references and 0 or more fresh
    symbol definitions.
  - The linkage of *file* introduces into `prog` *all* of the undefined symbol references and definitions from *file*. The linker
    can't pick and choose among them<sup>5</sup>.
  - If a definition of a **ToDo** symbol `sym` is found with these additions then `sym` becomes *resolved and defined* by that
    definition, whether or not it was already *resolved*.
- **If** *file* **is an static library:** It a package of object files: its
  symbol information is their symbol information.

  - For each **ToDo** symbol `sym`, the package is searched for an object file that provides a definition of `sym`.
  - The first object file found, if any, that provides a definition is extracted from the package and input to the linkage just like an object file input explicitly.
    Thus `sym` is *resolved and defined*.
  - The package is then iteratively searched for further symbol resolutions until it yields none.
  - Object files within the package that do not provide any needed definitions might as well not exist.
- **If** *file* **is a dynamic library:**

  - For each **ToDo** symbol `sym`, *file*'s symbol information is searched for `sym`.
  - If `sym` appears there as *defined*, it becomes *resolved* but *not defined*. It is carried forward in the **ToDo** list as *resolved*, along
    with the identity of *file*.
- If at any point object files are linked into `prog` that would cause it to contain multiple definitions of the same symbol,
  a *multiple definition* linkage error results, and does not result otherwise<sup>6</sup>.
- At end of linkage:

  - If the **ToDo** list contains any *unresolved* symbols, an *unresolved symbol* error
    results<sup>7</sup>.
  - Otherwise, each `sym` remaining in the **ToDo** list has been resolved by a definition
    provided by a known dynamic library *lib*:
    `sym` then becomes defined by *lib*'s definition<sup>8</sup>.

Note that per the Usual Logic, it is possible for `sym` to resolved at most twice, and defined at most
once. `sym` will be resolved twice if it is first resolved, but not defined, with a definition
furnished by a dynamic library, and later in the linkage is resolved again, and defined, by a
definition from a linked object file (which might have been extracted from a static library).

**Four variations of knocking out**

From the Usual Logic as described, it follows that:

1. Where a definition of `sym` is provided by an explicitly linked object file *obj*, *obj* is uncondionally linked, `sym` is resolved and defined.

   1. Any later provider that is a library, static or dynamic, is knocked out - because the linker will not even search it for `sym`.
   2. Any *preceding* provider that is a dynamic library is knocked out - because it can at most resolve `sym`, not define it.
2. Where the first provider of `sym` is a static libary member *arc(obj)*, *obj* is extracted and linked. Then 1.1 kicks in.
3. Where the first provider of `sym` is a shared library, `sym` is resolved, but not defined as long as there are more input files.
   Any later provider that is a library, static or dynamic, is knocked out  - because the linker will
   not even search it for `sym`.

---

**Extra: Linux GCC examples of knocking out** `operator  new(std::size_t)`

From now on the distinctions of terminology that I set aside early are back in force, and I call a dynamic library a *shared library*, in GNU/Linux usage (a.k.a Dynamic Shared Object, DSO).

I'm using:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 13.2.0-4ubuntu3) 13.2.0
```

The system static linker is

```
$ ld --version
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.41
```

And the system dynamic linker is:

```
$ ld.so --version
ld.so (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.38-1ubuntu6.1) stable release version 2.38.
```

Some source files:

**main.cpp**

Calls `operator new(std::side_t)` and prints `42` on success.

```
#include <iostream>

// extern void * operator new(std::size_t); - implicitly declared

int main(void){
    int *pi = new int(42);
    std::cout << *pi << std::endl;
    delete pi; 
    return 0;
}
```

**new_v1.cpp**

A knock-out implementation of `operator new(std::side_t)`.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <new>

void* operator new(std::size_t sz)
{
    std::printf("operator new v1: new(size_t), size = %zu\n", sz);
    if (sz == 0) {
        ++sz;
    }
    if (void *ptr = std::malloc(sz)) {
        return ptr;
    }
    throw std::bad_alloc{};
}
```

**new_v2.cpp**

Another knock-out implementation of `operator new(std::side_t)`.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <new>

void* operator new(std::size_t sz)
{
    std::printf("operator new v2: new(size_t), size = %zu\n", sz);
    if (sz == 0) {
        ++sz;
    }
    if (void *ptr = std::malloc(sz)) {
        return ptr;
    }
    throw std::bad_alloc{};
}
```

The sole difference between `new_v1.cpp` and `new_v2.cpp` is that the
the former defines `operator new(std::size_t sz)` so as to log its invocation
on the console as `operator new v1`, whereas the latter will log `operator new v2`.

**Prepare some linkage resources**

Regular object files compiled from `main.cpp`,
`new_v1.cpp` and `new_v2.cpp`:

```
$ g++ -c -o main.o -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.cpp
$ g++ -c -o new_v1.o -Wall -Wextra -pedantic new_v1.cpp
$ g++ -c -o new_v2.o -Wall -Wextra -pedantic new_v2.cpp
```

Relocatable object files for linkage in shared libaries, compiled from
`new_v1.cpp` and `new_v2.cpp`:

```
$ g++ -c -fPIC -o new_v1_r.o -Wall -Wextra -pedantic new_v1.cpp
$ g++ -c -fPIC -o new_v2_r.o -Wall -Wextra -pedantic new_v2.cpp
```

Shared librares linked respectively from `new_v1_r.o` and `new_v2_r.o`:

```
$ g++ -shared -o libnew_v1.so new_v1_r.o
$ g++ -shared -o libnew_v2.so new_v2_r.o
```

Finally a static library containing `new_v1.o` and `new_v2.o`:

```
$ ar rcs libnews.a new_v1.o new_v2.o  # `ar` is the GNU archiver
```

The object files are packaged in the order inserted:

```
$ ar t libnew.a
new_v1.o
new_v2.o
```

and `operator new(std::size_t)` is defined in each of them:

```
$ nm --defined-only -C libnew.a | grep 'operator new'
0000000000000000 T operator new(unsigned long)
0000000000000000 T operator new(unsigned long)
```

**How is** `operator new(std::size_t)` **identified to the linker?**

I need to know the mangled function name to which the C++ compiler translates
`operator new(std::size_t)` for the linker, because I want to trace it in
linkages.

Here are the raw undefined symbols in `main.o`:

```
$ nm -u main.o
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 U _ZdlPvm
                 U _ZNSolsEi
                 U _ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E
                 U _Znwm
                 U _ZSt21ios_base_library_initv
                 U _ZSt4cout
                 U _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
```

Nothing there is obviously our operator, so let's look again with demangling turned on:

```
$ nm -uC main.o
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 U operator delete(void*, unsigned long)
                 U std::ostream::operator<<(int)
                 U std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))
                 U operator new(unsigned long)
                 U std::ios_base_library_init()
                 U std::cout
                 U std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)
```

`operator new(unsigned long)` is our function, mangled name is `_Znwm`.

**Baseline static and dynamic linkages, no knock-outs**

We'll link a program `prog` using `main.o` that invokes the default `operator new` from `libstdc++`. We'll
ask the linker to `-trace-symbol=_Znwm` so we can see where it's referenced and
resolved. Link it dynamically per default, then again statically:

```
$ g++ -o prog main.o -Wl,-trace-symbol=_Znwm    # dynamic linkage
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: reference to _Znwm  # g++ ultimately delegates linkage to `ld`
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/libstdc++.so: definition of _Znwm ...
...[cut]...
```

`_Znwm` is referenced but not defined in `main.o`, as we know. A definition was provided `libstdc++.so`. But, let's check it out in in the symbol tables of
`prog`:

```
$ readelf --wide --syms prog
    Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 13 entries:
       Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
         ...[cut]...
         3: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _Znwm@GLIBCXX_3.4 (3)
         ...[cut]...

    Symbol table '.symtab' contains 45 entries:
       Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
         ...[cut]...
        31: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _Znwm@GLIBCXX_3.4
         ...[cut]...
```

`_Znwm` is *undefined* (`Ndx` = `UND`) in both the dynamic symbol `.dynsym` and the
global symbol table `.symtab`, although it was resolved by a definition found in shared
library `libstdc++.so` identified by `_Znwm@GLIBCXX_3.4`. (The suffix
`@GLIBCXX_3.4` is a dynamic [symbol versioning](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/VERSION.html) suffix that the linker parses.)

Since `_Znwm` was resolved but not defined, it could be defined in a
different linkage even *after* `libstdc++.so` was consumed, knocking out the
default definition "retrospectively". But as things are,
the default definition will be bound at runtime by `ld.so`, resulting in:

```
$ ./prog
42
```

We can view the notes that `ld` has dropped in `prog` so that `ld.so` knew what its immediate dynamic
dependencies are. They are the *dynamic section* in `prog`:

```
$ readelf -d prog | egrep \(Dynamic\|Tag\|NEEDED\)
Dynamic section at offset 0x2d98 contains 28 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

And we can see the recursively exhaustive list of dynamic dependencies that `ld.so` arrives at:

```
$ ld.so --list ./prog
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff9d743000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f49d5800000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f49d5400000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f49d5715000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => ld.so (0x00007f49d5ac2000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f49d5a87000)
```

(The `ld.so --list ./prog` command is normally invoked via `ldd ./prog`).

Next, the static linkage:

```
$ g++ -static -o prog main.o -Wl,-trace-symbol=_Znwm    # static linkage
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: reference to _Znwm
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/libstdc++.a(new_op.o): definition of _Znwm
...[cut]...
```

This time, the provider of `_Znwm` is the archive member `libstdc++.a(new_op.o)`. Here's the
global symbol table of `prog` (a statically program has no dynamic symbol
table), filtered for `_Znwm`:

```
$ readelf --wide --syms prog | egrep \(Symbol\|Ndx\|GLOBAL.*_Znwm\)
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 7447 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
  2593: 0000000000405340    53 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    7 _Znwm
```

This time `_Znwm` is *defined* (`Ndx` = a number), because it's provided by a linked object file. But the default definition could still be knocked out by one from another object file linked before `libstdc++.a` was reached. The program behaves just the same:

```
$ ./prog
42
```

Now I'll do linkages that demonstrate each of the four knock-out variations,
making two of them static linkages and two of them dynamic. I'll also
make one of them illustrate *knockout chaining*.

**Knock-out type 1.1: (static linkage)**

The first provider of `_Znwm` is an object file `new_v1.o` that provides definition V1. The default definition
provided later by `libstdc++.a` is knocked out.

```
$ g++ -static -o prog main.o new_v1.o -Wl,-trace-symbol=_Znwm
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: reference to _Znwm
/usr/bin/ld: new_v1.o: definition of _Znwm
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/libstdc++.a(numeric_members.o): reference to _Znwm
...[cut]...
```

Proof:

```
$ ./prog
operator new v1: new(size_t), size = 4
42
```

`libstc++.a` was not searched for `_Znwm` because it was already defined,
but many object files were linked from `libstdc++.a` to define other symbols for
the program, plenty of them containing references to `_Znwm`. The first such
archive member - listed - was `libstdc++.a(numeric_members.o)`

**Knock-out type 1.2: (dynamic linkage)**

The first provider of `_Znwm` is the shared standard library `libstdc++.so` But an explicitly
linked object file `new_v1.o` provides definition V1 later. The *preceding* default definition from
`libstdc++.so` is knocked out.

```
$ g++ -o prog main.o -l stdc++ new_v2.o -Wl,-trace-symbol=_Znwm
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: reference to _Znwm
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/libstdc++.so: definition of _Znwm
/usr/bin/ld: new_v2.o: definition of _Znwm
```

Proof:

```
$ ./prog
operator new v2: new(size_t), size = 4
42
```

**Knock-out type 2: (static linkage)**

The first provider of `_Znwm` is an archive member `libnews.a(new_v1.o)` that provides
definition V1. The default definition provided later by `libstdc++.a` is knocked out.

```
$ g++ -static -o prog main.o -L . -l news  -Wl,-trace-symbol=_Znwm
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: reference to _Znwm
/usr/bin/ld: ./libnews.a(new_v1.o): definition of _Znwm
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/libstdc++.a(monetary_members.o): reference to _Znwm
...[cut]...
```

Proof:

```
$ ./prog
operator new v1: new(size_t), size = 4
42
```

The difference between this example and example 1.1 is merely that the linker linked archive
member `libnews.a(new_v1.o)` because it was *searching* for a definition when
`libnews.a` was reached, not because it was obliged to link an explicit object file.

The V2 definition provided by `libnews.a(new_v2.o)` might as well not exist.

**Knock-out type 3 with knockout chaining: (dynamic linkage)**

For this one we'll throw more than the minimum into the linkage, (a) to stress the V2
definition provided first knocks out *all* later library definitions - user-defined or default, whether in a static or shared
library, (b) to illustrate *knockout chaining*.

The first provider of `_Znwm` is a shared library `libnew_v2,so`. All later library definitions are knocked out:

- A later V1 definition provided by shared library `libnew_v1.so`
- The standard library definition provided later by static library `libstdc++.a`
- The standard library definition provided later still by shared library `libstdc++.so`, which is linked after all the rest by default.

But also, for other symbols, the standard definitions provided by `libstdc++.a` knock out the
standard definitions provided later by `libstdc++.so`.

```
$ g++ -o prog main.o -L . -l new_v2 -l new_v1 -l:libstdc++.a -Wl,-rpath=$(pwd),-trace-symbol=_Znwm
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: reference to _Znwm
/usr/bin/ld: ./libnew_v2.so: definition of _Znwm
/usr/bin/ld: ./libnew_v1.so: reference to _Znwm
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/libstdc++.a(monetary_members.o): reference to _Znwm
...[cut]...
```

From:

```
$ ./prog
operator new v2: new(size_t), size = 4
42
```

it's clear that the `-l new_v2` definition knocked out the `-l new_v1` definition, the
`-l:libstdc++.a`, and the definition from the `libstdc++.so`.

But the static standard library `libstdc++.a` then knocked
out everything else from the later implicit `libstdc++.so`. This chained knock-out has no visible runtime affect on the behaviour of our particular program. But we can detect it by filtering for some of the other standard overloads of `operator new` in the
(demangled) symbol tables of `prog`:

```
$ readelf -W --syms prog | egrep \(\Symbol\|GLOBAL.*_Zn\|Ndx\) | c++filt
Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 4061 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
    34: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND operator new(unsigned long)
  1158: 00000000000fa530    30 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   16 operator new[](unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&)
  3558: 00000000000fa520     9 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   16 operator new[](unsigned long)
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 5120 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
  1730: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND operator new(unsigned long)
  4346: 00000000000fa520     9 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   16 operator new[](unsigned long)
  4389: 00000000000fa530    30 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   16 operator new[](unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&)
```

Our own V2 `operator new(unsigned long)` appears as undefined ( `Ndx` = `UND`),
because it was resolved in shared library `libnew_v2.so`. But its two `operator new[]` colleagues are defined (`Ndx`= a number). That's because they were defined in object files linked from `libstdc++.a`, not resolved by `libstdc++.so`.

**Let's cause a multiple definition error to finish!**

```
$ g++ -o prog main.o new_v2.o new_v1.o
/usr/bin/ld: new_v1.o: in function `operator new(unsigned long)':
new_v1.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `operator new(unsigned long)'; new_v2.o:new_v2.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

or alternatively:

```
$ g++ -o prog main.o -l:libstdc++.a new_v1.o
/usr/bin/ld: new_v1.o: in function `operator new(unsigned long)':
new_v1.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `operator new(unsigned long)'; /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/libstdc++.a(new_op.o):(.text._Znwm+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The *only* way to cause a multiple definition error at link time (as opposed to compiletime) is to require
the linker to link two object files into the program that both provide
definitions of the same symbol: in the first linkage, `new_v2.o` + `new_v1.o`;
in the second `libstdc++.a(new_op.o)` + `new_v1.o`. The only definitions that get *into the program* at buildtime are the ones that get in from object files. The ones finally resolved in shared libraries at buildtime are just the ones that aren't knocked out, and they don't get in until runtime.

---

1. Of course, compiler development exerts an influence on linker development, but since a linker
   is blind to source languages and purposed to serve any and all compilers in a system, the influence
   is in the realm of *nudge*.
2. If `sym` is a data symbol its assigned meaning is a data value. If `sym` is a function symbol then its assigned meaning is the execution
   of a particular code sequence (the compiler having arranged that any arguments required per the function signature are correctly set up
   on entry).
3. A mere *mention* of `sym` (in compiler terminology, a *declaration*) isn't a use: a use evaluates the *meaning* `sym`
4. We're ignoring *weak symbols*, which are an ELF-specific wrinkle not relevant here.
5. Say, by taking just the definitions that will shrink the **ToDo** list: that way, the **ToDo** list would never get populated at all.
6. Compiletime multiple definition errors are also possible, but we don't get to linkage until they're fixed.
7. Different linkers may diagnose an *unresolved symbol* error in different words. The Microsoft linker reports "unresolved external symbol `sym`". The GNU Linux linker reports "undefined reference to `sym`".
8. So what happens if a dynamic library *libB* both references `sym` and provides a definition, but
   `sym` becomes defined in a linkage by an early dynamic library whose definition is found first:
   does *libA*'s definition knock out *libB*'s *internally* as well as externally? Are *libB*s own references of
   `sym` bound to *libA*'s definition or its own? It depends on the tool chain. For the GNU/Linux ELF linker,
   *libA*'s definition wins by default; but the prior linkage of *libB* itself could be varied to spurn any external
   definition for its own references. For a Microsoft PE binary the compiler preempts the choice: a definition of `sym`
   can be dynamically exported or dynamically imported but not both; so if *libB* exports its own definition it cannot be knocked out internally.